# cannot access dervied class properties when object created using base class

Tags: c#, object, inheritance, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I cannot access derived class properties from base class object name.

My motivation is i need eliminate properties repeating in class and need to create object using base class name.

```
public abstract class Request
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }        
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public bool IsRejected { get; set; }

    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
public class Permission : Request
{
    public DateTime FromTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToTime { get; set; }
    public PermissionType PermissionType { get; set; }       
}
public class Leave: Request
{
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
    public LeaveType LeaveType { get; set; }

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            

        Request req = new Permission();
        req.Reason = 1;
        req.Reason = "232";
        req.FromTime = DateTime.Now; // Here i'm getting error as 'Request does not              contain definition'
        req.ToTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1); // Here i'm getting error as 'Request does not              contain definition'
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of `req` is `Request` even though it is instantiated with a `Permission`.

The property `FromTime` exists only in `Permission` and not the base class.

You should do this

```
Permission p = new Permission();
p.FromTime = DateTime.Now; //now works`
```

You could cast req to `Permission` if you need to use the properties from `Permission`

`((Permission)req).FromTime = ...`

Comment: Ric -> On which scenario we need to create object like "Request req = new Permission();"

Comment: If you only need to access the properties/methods from the base without knowing or caring of the actual derived type such as Permission or Leave or create a method that only accepts a parameter of type `Request` such as `void DoStuff(Request r) { r.IsApproved = false; }` which would work for all derived types of `Request`

Answer (score 0):

you are defining your variable as the base class so she will have access only peropriedades the same

```
Permission req = new Permission();
```